# What are the conditions of wave function continuity when solving for Dirac Spinors as done in "Klein paradox" paper by Novoselov?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, spinors, graphene, quantum-tunneling

In the paper [*"Chiral tunneling and Klein paradox"*](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0604323) paper by Katsnelson, Novoselov, and Geim, they use the wave function for Dirac spinors. What are the conditions for continuity of the wave function here? I want to know those conditions because I am getting two different reflection coefficients for both spinors.

Comment: Welcome to physics.SE! I have linked the paper you probably are talking about, if it's the wrong one, please edit in the correct link. Also, do you have any reason to suspect that anything other than "continuous" and "normalizable" is demanded of the wave function here?

Comment: Actually i was trying to reproduce the results stated in the paper,  so i was just asking that what all are the conditions i can apply to get it. As there two spinors containing two different "r" and "t", so how to get desired reflection and transmission coefficients?